# how to create Ec2 instance with (windows 2019 cup 1 Ram 32 Gb internet speed 20000 MBPS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, awstats

I have to create a aws ec2 instance with network speed 20000 MBPS. like when i take rdp and check network speed on speed test , my speed should be 20000MBPS.

Answer (score 1):

20,000MBps (megabytes per second) is 160Gbps. You may also mean 20,000Mbps (megabits per second), which is 20Gbps. That's a bit of a difference, so I'll assume the former as that's what you suggested.

Unfortunately a single AWS instance can't reach that bandwidth. According to [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/introducing-amazon-ec2-m5n-m5dn-r5n-and-r5dn-instances-featuring-100-gbps-of-network-bandwidth/)

> Amazon Web Services (AWS) announces the availability of Amazon EC2
>   M5n, M5dn, R5n, and R5dn instances that can utilize up to 100 Gbps of
>   network bandwidth, and Elastic Fabric Adapter (EFA) for HPC/ML
>   workloads. These instances offer significantly higher network
>   performance across all instance sizes, ranging from 25 Gbps of network
>   bandwidth on smaller instance sizes to 100 Gbps of network bandwidth
>   on the largest instance size, and support automatic encryption of
>   in-transit traffic between instances.

The m5dn.24xlarge instance type can do 100Gbps, it currently costs $6.50 per hour, or $4650 per month. If you can divide your load, two m5dn.16xlarge would cost $4.32 per hour each, or $6220 per month.

You will likely have to do a LOT of optimization of your stack to reach that bandwidth, and that's inside AWS bandwidth rather than internet. You will have to use many threads and the software will have to be very efficient, with the software and OS very well tuned.

I'm curious why you need a single server with such high bandwidth. I suspect your question doesn't accurately reflect what you actually need.